# renaming files without the **rename** command

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have a directory of files,

```
Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session1.xml
Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session2.xml
Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session3.xml
Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session4.xml
...
Measurements Panama 2009-03-22 Session10.xml
```

and I want to remove the blank spaces and the `-` dash characters. I don't want to use the **rename** command because I don't know perl or regular expressions. From another post a recommendation for removing part of a file name was:

```
for f in *.png; do mv $f ${f#image}; done
```

this looks nice. I can't figure out what the `#` character does (I assume it removes the string "image" from the file names?), anyways -- how do I remove the spaces and dashes?

I get an error that the files are not a directory when doing

```
[jings]s0128943: for f in *.xml; do mv $f ${f//[ -]/};done

mv: target `MeasurementsPanama20090322Session10.xml' is not a directory

mv: target `MeasurementsPanama20090322Session1.xml' is not a directory
```

etc for all the files.

Comment: Why do you think there will be an easy way without perl or regex?

Comment: I don't know, maybe im wrong. Why doesn't the attempted script work?? plz...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find information the `${...}` substitutions in your shell's man page, for example [bash(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/bash).  The most common:

- `${var#word}` remove shortest prefix: the value of variable `var` with the `word` prefix (if any) removed;
- `${var%word}` remove shortest suffix: the value of variable `var` with the `word` suffix removed (if any).
- `${var/pattern/replacement}` remove first occurrence of pattern
- `${var//pattern/replacment}` remove all occurrences of pattern

So, in your example `${f#image}` expands to the value of `f` (e.g.,
`image01.png`) removing the `image` prefix, so it yields the value
`01.png`.

The `word` and `replacement` part in the `${...}` expansions are
subject to the same wildcard expansions as filenames; therefore,
if you want to remove spaces and `-`, you could use `${f//[ -]/}`
(replaces any occurrence of characters  and `-` with a null string.

All details on the man page.

Comment: I get an error that the files are not a directory[jings]s0128943: for f in *.xml; do mv $f ${f//[ -]/};done
mv: target `MeasurementsPanama20090322Session10.xml' is not a directory
mv: target `MeasurementsPanama20090322Session1.xml' is not a directory

Comment: @Vass Since your file names contain spaces you need to quote them, otherwise the shell will expand `$f` to separate words `Measurements`, `Panama`, etc. and thus make `mv` think that you want to move files `Measuremens`, `Panama`, etc. into a single`MeasurementsPanama...` which must then be a directory. Use `for f in *.xml; do mv "$f" "${f//[ -]/}"; done` instead. (See Gilles' answer as well.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the perl `rename` (e.g. because you're on Debian or Ubuntu), it is the simplest way of skinning this particular cat (as in an individual cat — there are plenty of tools for mass renaming, and searching the archives of this site and [Super User](https://superuser.com/) should find all the major ones).

```
rename 's/[- ]//g' *.xml
```

That being said, your script would have worked if you had followed the most important shell programming principle: **all variable substitutions must be double-quoted**. (Why do you need this extra bit of syntax fluff? Because there are cases where you actually want the unquoted behavior. But these cases are rather rare.)

```
for f in *.xml; do mv "$f" "${f//[ -]/}"; done
```

With zsh, you wouldn't need to write a loop: you could use the convenient `zmv` function.

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(*.xml)' '${1//[- ]/}'
```

Comment: thanks alot. perl is a bit beyond me as well as zsh, but the other part is great.

Answer (score 1):

You might also use sed to build the new name. There it would be

```
for i in *.xml; do mv "$i" `echo "$i" | sed -e "s/[ -]//g"`; done
```

Comment: Backticks are deprecated. Recommendet is $(...) instead, which is easy to nest, and not so easy to be overseen or confused with apostrophs: `for i in *.xml; do mv "$i" $(echo "$i" | sed -e "s/[ -]//g"); done`